# Disabling hotkeys in firefox addon

Tags: firefox-addon, xul, hotkeys

Is there a way to disable keyboard shortcuts (hotkeys) in a firefox add-on?

Comment: Why don't you google it instead asking in here ?

Comment: Seriously? Wow what a great idea i never thought of!!!

Comment: Yes, googling is the way to go. Look for "keypress event", `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`. If you want a more detailed answer you should provide a better explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I KNOW about google and sure I DID search this topic. Better explanation? I'm building an addon and i need to disable hotkeys and all i found was creating shortcuts and adding events to them, but nothing about handling already made shortcuts.

Comment: I googled it, and I found this question!

Answer (score 1):

If your addon has an overlay for browser.xul, an alternative to handling the "keypress" event is to use script in the "load" handler to remove the relevant  elements from the browser XUL document like this:

```
var key = document.getElementById("key_openDownloads");
key.parentNode.removeChild(key);
```

In case it's not obvious, this removes the hotkey for opening the download manager. You can see all the keys here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla2.0/source/browser/base/content/browser-sets.inc. This is for Mozilla 2.0 (i.e. Firefox 4.0.x). You can change the tree using the dropdown at the top of the page, but I don't think these keys or their IDs change very often anyway.

Depending on your use case, this might be more convenient than catching "keypress".

Comment: Thanks Matthew for your decent reply. Some commands are still working like copy and paste. I tried "key_copy" and it didn't work. I also tried getting the command "cmd_copy" and disabling it by setting disabled=true but still nothing. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Matthew, I think you've gone over to the dark side. That code should be reason enough for the add-on to be immediately rejected on addons.mozilla.org. You probably use things like this in Webrunner but I cannot imagine a valid reason why an *extension* should ever do this.

Comment: @Wladimir,  what's your problem! I can understand your feelings of not wanting to help, but discouraging others to help me is really sick! I'm developing this add on for private usage based on these requirements and not for public.

Comment: @Sara: I am always willing to help - in this particular case I was simply trying to point out that you should tell *what* you are trying to achieve, not *how* you want to do it (e.g. "I need to stop the user from switching away from my window." is better than "How do I block Alt-Tab key?" because blocking Alt-Tab is the wrong solution in the first place). And the code in this answer will almost certainly not solve your problem, whatever it might be; that's the point of my previous comment.

Comment: @Wladimir: well the nice thing about this approach is that you can simply disable e.g. "key_cut" by ID without having to figure out what the hotkeys are for each platform (keeping in mind that the modifiers often differ). Why do you think this is so evil?

Comment: @Matthew Gertner: Because that's an operation that cannot be undone - once you've removed the hotkey it cannot be reinstated. And killing the downloads hotkey in the browser sounds pretty bad. A more sensible (and reversible) approach would be to disable the command corresponding with the hotkey (via `disabled` attribute). But it really depends on what the point of all this is - something we still don't know.

Comment: @wladimir The point is that the add on is for kids and we don't want any buttons hit by mistake to do something. Trying to limit their control as possible is the point. @matthew still not working on copy/ paste commands

Comment: Okay, I see your point. Maybe I'll try to take a less heavy-handed approach in WebRunnner. Sara: I'm not sure why that is but maybe overriding the "keypress" event would be the way to go for those commands.